# Easy way to set a single character of an NSString to uppercase

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I would like to change the first character of an NSString to uppercase. Unfortunately, `- (NSString *)capitalizedString` converts the first letter of every word to uppercase. Is there an easy way to convert just a single character to uppercase?

I'm currently using:

```
NSRange firstCharRange = NSMakeRange(0,1);
NSString* firstCharacter = [dateString substringWithRange:firstCharRange];
NSString* uppercaseFirstChar = [firstCharacter originalString];
NSMutableString* capitalisedSentence = [originalString mutableCopy];
[capitalisedSentence replaceCharactersInRange:firstCharRange withString:uppercaseFirstChar];
```

Which seems a little convoluted but at least makes no assumptions about the encoding of the underlying unicode string.

Comment: There is a good discussion of case mapping here: http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/casemappings  In the terminology of that page, is what you want to do a simple character mapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `NSString` is immutable, what you have seems to be a good way to do what you want to do. The implementations of `(NSString*)uppercaseString` and similar methods probably look very much like what you've written, as they return a new `NSString` instead of modifying the one you sent the message to.

Comment: it seems that an underscore is considered a valid separator so foo_bar will be converted to "Foo_Bar"

Answer (score 17):

Very similar approach to what you have but a little more condense:

```
 NSString *capitalisedSentence = 
    [dateString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0,1)  
    withString:[[dateString  substringToIndex:1] capitalizedString]];
```

Comment: yeah, optimised for cr/lf ;-) I like to let the optimiser take my temporaries out.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement, but it was for characters within the string. This assuming i is your index to the character you want to uppercase this worked for me:

```
curword = [curword stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(i,1) 
           withString:[[curword substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)] capitalizedString]];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you profile these solutions they are much slower then doing this:

```
NSMutableString *capitolziedString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:originalString];
NSString *firstChar = [[capitolziedString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,1)] uppercaseString];
[capitolziedString replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1) withString:firstChar];
```

in testing on an iphone 4 running iOS 5:
@doomspork's solution ran in 0.115750 ms
while above ran in 0.064250 ms;

in testing on an Simulator running iOS 5:
@doomspork's solution ran in 0.021232 ms
while above ran in 0.007495 ms;

Comment: If this function were being run repeatedly it might be of concern that your solution runs in 1/3 to 1/2 the time, but as is, we're looking for the "easiest" solution, which could be read as the most legible.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare My solution isn't that much harder to read then your's is and if your going to encapsulate the solution inside a category, that you wont probably ever look at again, then you should build the fastest solution so you don't have some weird performance problem later because you wrote inefficient code.

Answer (score 1):

Aiming for maximum readability, make a `category` on `NSString` and give it this function:

```
NSString *capitalizeFirstLetter(NSString *string) {
    NSString *firstCapital = [string substringToIndex:1].capitalizedString;
    return [string stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1) withString:firstCapital];
}
```

Then in your code where you want it:

```
NSString *capitalizedSentence = capitalizeFirstLetter(dateString);
```

This kind of code rarely belongs in the spot where you need it and should generally be factored away into a utility class or a `category` to improve legibility.